# Is it possible to use Choose File in Robot Framework to Choose a folder?

Tags: robotframework

I'm wondering is it possible, with some parameters to use Choose File keyword to Choose a folder instead of a single file?

The HTML for the file upload input is similiar to the folder upload input in our application.

File

```
<input data-automation-id="upload-multiple-files" id="upload-multiple-files" multiple="multiple" name="uploadFiles" type="file" accept="*" title="Select files to upload">
```

Folder

```
<input data-automation-id="uploadFolder" directory="" id="uploadFolder" multiple="multiple" name="uploadFiles" type="file" webkitdirectory="" accept="*" title="Select folders to upload">
```

For fileupload `Choose File  xpath=//input[@type="file"] 
 C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\robottestfile.txt` works. But for folder upload `Choose File  xpath=//input[@type="file"]  C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\` doesn't.

Sorry if this has a simple solution, I have been unable to find one yet.

Tried Helios answer and it got me to a new place.

Now I have

```
Send folder
    @{my_file_list}=    OperatingSystem.List Files In Directory    ${path_to_directory}
    FOR    ${file}    IN    @{my_file_list}
    \    ${result}=    Choose File    ${my_locator}    ${file}
# Finish this test
#     Close Browser  
*** Keywords ***

*** Variables ***
${my_locator}  xpath=//input[@title="Select files to upload"]
${path_to_directory}  C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\alfrescotestfolder
```

But I get this error:

ValueError: File 'alfresctotestexcel.xlsx' does not exist on the local file system.

alfrescotestexcel.xlsx is in that target folder...

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no ready made solution with `Choose File`. You have to get the filenames in the folder, and then `Choose File` for each.

```
@{my_file_list}=    OperatingSystem.List Files In Directory    ${path_to_directory}
: FOR    ${file}    IN    @{my_file_list}
\    ${result}=    Choose File    ${my_locator}    ${path_to_directory}${/}${file}
```

Comment: Thanks! Opens a whole new world for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @{my_file_list}=    OperatingSystem.List Files In Directory    C:\\Users\\Desktop\\My pics
    FOR    ${file}    IN    @{my_file_list}
        ${result}=    Choose File    //input[@type="file"]    C:\\Users\\Desktop\\My pics\\${file}
        Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    120    2s    Element Should Be Visible    ${xpath_for_BrowseFiles_button}
    END
```

I have added full path in file selection. Please try these, this will work for you.

**Note:**
If you have "Browse files" or "choose file" button then use this line **Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    120    2s    Element Should Be Visible    ${xpath_for_BrowseFiles_button}.**

Comment: Thank you too! This fixed the problem!